# Possible backslash escaping issue when trying to perform a regex

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have the following sentence which is within a much larger string variable:

```
New Component <b>TEST</b> is successfully registered.
```

I'm trying to perform a regex match to find this sentence within the string. The word TEST is variable and can be any word.

I'm using the following pattern in regexr which runs fine:

```
New Component <b>\w*<\/b> is successfully registered.
```

In my java code I have to write it as

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("New Component <b>\\w*<\\/b> is successfully registered.");
Matcher m = p.matcher(result.toString()); 
if (m.matches()) {
  System.out.println("hurray!");
}
```

This is because I need to escape the backslashes. However the pattern is not receiving a match in the php code and hurray is not printed. Is there an issue with the backslashes or the way I have used them here that is causing the matcher to fail?

Comment: your code is anything, but *not* php - looks more like java to me? also, it's not because of escaping, but because you didn't specify a  capture group. try `New Component <b>(\w*)<\/b> is successfully registered.`

Comment: Sorry about that you're right it should be java not php

Comment: I tried the pattern you suggested but its still not working, if it matches in regexr though the pattern I used should be ok right?

Comment: try https://regex101.com/ - it also comes with a handy code-generator-function that even supports java

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `.*` to the start and end of the pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*New Component <b>\\w*<\\/b> is successfully registered\..*");
```

Your pattern is trying to match the string, however it won't match as it is part of a larger string, so any characters before or after the target string will not be accepted by the regular expression and cause it to fail.

`.*` tells the matcher to accept 0 or more of ANY character before and after your target string.

Edit: Also if you want to match the fullstop at the end of the line, you should escape the fullstop with `\.`, this is because the dot has a special meaning in regex, it means any character.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @dahui's answer, the other option is to switch `m.matches()` with [`m.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

`.matches()` requires the regex to match the entire string.
`.find()` required the regex to match any substring of the string.

**Edit:**
Running the following *does* print "hurray!" when I run it:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("New Component <b>\\w*<\\/b> is successfully registered.");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("New Component <b>TEST</b> is successfully registered."); 
        if (m.matches()) {
          System.out.println("hurray!");
        }

    }

}
```

Is it possible `result.toString()` isn't what you think it is?

Comment: Changing it to m.find fixes the problem so thanks for that!